# jquery mouseover question

Tags: jquery, mouseover, html, mouseout

I have a jquery-script that triggers on mouseover on a div like this:

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <span class="mySpan">text text text</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that it acts like mouseout when i hover over the text and I dont want that. I could put an invisible div over it all and trigger the moseover on that but I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Any suggestions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [mouseleave](http://docs.jquery.it/Events/mouseleave) / [mouseenter](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter) not mouseout/mouseover

mouseleave fires when leaving the parent, while mouseout fires on children

Comment: Thanks. Mouseleave / mouseenter works fine in IE but not in FF. Now im using my solution for FF and yours for IE, not the prettiest but it works.

Comment: It was with this same problem and solved this with their response. Thank you!